# HttpURLConnection Max Throughput

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, httpserver

I was using the `HttpURLConnection` to make multiple short requests in the sequence to a server `HttpServer`. What is the maximum throughput that I can expect? I am not able to get it upwards of 25 records/second.

I need to get it upwards of atleast 5000 records/sec. Is this a right approach to use `HttpURLConnection`?

Below is my client code:

```
public class TestGatewayUser {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {

        byte[] bytes = TestGatewayUser.getDataAsBytes();
        Date d1 = new Date();
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i ) {

            URL url = new URL( "http://IP:PORT/fetchInfo" );
            HttpURLConnection conn = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
            byte[] bytes = TestGatewayUser.getDataAsBytes();

            conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( bytes.length ) );
            conn.setUseCaches( false );
            conn.setDoInput( true );
            conn.setDoOutput( true );
            conn.connect();
            OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
            out.write( bytes );
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1];
            while ( stream.read( b ) != -1 ) {
                bos.write( b );
            }
            byte[] byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
            stream.close();
            if ( i % 200 == 0 ) {
                System.out.println( 200.0 / ( new Date().getTime() - d1.getTime() ) * 1000 );
            }

           conn.disconnect();//**Should I use this or not? Java Doc says optional.**
        }
        Date d2 = new Date();
        System.out.println( d2.getTime() - d1.getTime() );
    }

    private static byte[] getDataAsBytes() throws IOException {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        buf.append( "1367249:2,4,5,31,32,35,59,68,77,389,532,558,353,30002,371" );
        return buf.toString().getBytes();
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: how is your test structured client-server wise? ie scores of clients each issuing scores of http POST each second OR 1 client issuing thousands of POSTs per sec?   there is some diff there on where you would start optimization and what would be done.  you will need to multithread the client code. https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java

Comment: What's the reason behind issuing thousands of requests?  Can you obtain the same data with a small number of requests, each fetching a large amount of data?  Establishing connection is expensive in terms of time.  The other thing you may want to look for is keep-alive connection, where you connect once and then send multiple requests.

Comment: @RobertRowntree, it is one client issuing thousands of POST requests oer second.

Comment: You need to rethink your architecture.  You just cannot do what you want.  There should be no need whatsoever to send that many requests.

Comment: We are trying to have communication over network between two processes. They expose HTTPServer and other tries to talk to that.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/v4EDq6mr  @57    has some sample, android threaded, client code that connects to 'parse.com' using multi-threaded (remove the android handler and replace with java callBack).  if you have 64 cores in your client you could use about 90 threads all hitting one domain with posts..  IMO should not be a big issue as long as you are comfortable with the threading in java concurrency package.

Comment: Do you control both of the machines, the client and the server?

Comment: What does the data look like, and how often do you expect it to change?

Comment: That said, two processes don't normally need to know about each other 5000x per second; consider editing the question and telling us what you're trying to do.

Comment: You keep HTTPUrlConnections alive by not calling `disconnect(),` and you should read into a byte array, not read a byte at a time. But I agree with the others that this is not going to work. It wouldn't work directly over a TCP socket, let alone over a heavyweight protocol like HTTP.

Comment: @DeanJ, the data can change anytime. Data will be a sequence of bytes with max payliad of 500 bytes. In our application, one node is querying another node for some data., and this happens continuously.

Comment: @EJP, thanks. But how do I keep the HTTPUrlConnections alive? I get an exception when I try to use the same connection twice. A snippet please?

Comment: What I said. Just use the same code without the disconnect call. The pooling happens behind the scenes. Don't try to reuse the HttpURLConnection object yourself. And don't set the content-length. It's done automatically for you.

Comment: Okay. So I still need to close the input and output streams as suggested right? Also what speeds I can expect with that, roughly?

Comment: Sigh. What part of 'same code without the disconnect' don't you understand? Just do what I said, and only what I said. I can't predict what speed you're going to get with your unknown hardware, server, and network.

Comment: Okay EJP. Thanks for suggestions :)

Comment: When I asked "how often can it change", why not have the server send a request to the client when the change actually happens, instead of flooding the network hard with matching responses?

Comment: Also, is 5000 an arbitrary number here?

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to get 5000 connections opened, data sent, and all 5000 connections closed in a second in this method, using one machine.

If you were able to do it on the client, you'd likely kill the server machine; most web apps that go over 100 q/s are serving mostly cached data.